# Grabbing an Activation ID key after first instance of a text string using Slmgr /dlv and Regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

Slmgr /dlv gives a list of licenses on any given computer. One is for the OS, one is called an "ESU" key, there are others depending on your system. I'm attempting to grab the first instance of an Activation ID that comes *after* the text "ESU", so I'm not grabbing the OS Activation key or any other for that matter.

With this code, I think it's grabbing the second instance of Activation ID after the text "ESU" or it's just grabbing the wrong key altogether. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
$Slmgr = cscript.exe C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv

switch -Regex ($slmgr | Out-String){'(?s)ESU.+Activation ID: (.+?)(?=\r?\n)'{

[PSCustomObject]@{

ActivationID = $Matches[1]
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: This is the result of slmgr /dlv below. It was grabbing the first instance of the Activation ID from the OS Key, but now it's grabbing the correct key from ESU section using (?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+) below in the comments.

[http://imgur.com/gallery/BIJcyqM](https://imgur.com/gallery/BIJcyqM)

But, the output is showing "Name", and "Value", where is I just need the # that is obfuscated alone to process it later.

[http://imgur.com/gallery/gVPMeHM](https://imgur.com/gallery/gVPMeHM)

**Update**

Apparently, on certain systems $Slmgr is an array, not a multiline string, so -match doesn’t work for a multiline regex.

I tried this, but it give me a bunch of additional info after the Activation key:

```
$Slmgr = cscript.exe C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv
$Slmgr -match '(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)'
$Slmgr -join "'r'n" -match '(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)'
$ActivationID = $matches[1]
```

Looking at `$ActivationID`, it does have the Activation key in the beginning, then is shows “ ‘r ‘n “ that I have in my code, then a bunch of stuff after it as well like installation keys, certificate info. I think that my –join in my code is throwing something off.

Any ideas what I’m doing wrong or a better way of what I’m trying to accomplish?

Comment: You probably want `(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)`. Can you share the `$Slmgr` output?

Comment: What extra text? `$matches[1]` only contains the contents of Group 1 What is your input text?

Comment: Apologies for the extra comment, this is the extra text I was talking about. I believe I didn't run the whole line of script correctly before. http://imgur.com/gallery/gVPMeHM I basically just need the # that is covered to be put into a variable that I can process later in the script. Thank you again.

Comment: Please post the `$Slmgr` variable text in the question body. Specify the exact text you want to get from there.

Comment: I hope I captured what was needed in the question body and it makes sense? I appreciate your time and this is very helpful.

Comment: The first image is the GUI version of the slmgr results. If run in a PowerShell ISE, you'd see the exact same thing in text. I think that is what you were asking? The second image in the comment body is the result of the code above, but only with the change you gave: (?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)  I basically just need the Activation ID # so I can store it in a variable. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I think you just do not need the switch, use `$Slmgr -match '(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)'` and then `$ActivationID = $matches[1]`. Then, `$ActivationID` will hold the right value.

Comment: I finally got around to testing this today, and will do this steps you mentioned above as well. I tried to run this on a Server 2008 R2 system, right-clicked on the script "Run as Administrator", and the window opened up for a second and just disappeared. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you again.

Comment: I do not know what you clicked and what window disappeared, the code I shared should be run in the Powershell console.

Comment: Please update the question with new findings and add a comment below the answer to let know of your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using

```
$slmgr = cscript.exe C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv
$ActivationID = If ($slmgr -match '(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)') {$matches[1]} Else {""}
```

The `(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)` regex matches

- `(?s)` -  `RegexOptions.Singleline` option on to make `.` match newlines, too
- `ESU` - an `ESU` substring
- `.+?` - one or more chars, as few as possible
- `Activation ID:` - a literal phrase
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than CR and LF.

Regarding the update, if your input is an array and you need to convert it to a string you need:

```
$slmgr = cscript.exe C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv
$slmgrString = $slmgr -join "`r`n"
$ActivationID = If ($slmgrString -match '(?s)ESU.+?Activation ID:\s*([^\r\n]+)') {$matches[1]} Else {""}
```